# Killing the spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and spark both .

I have a code in scala which executes quieres in while loop one after the other.

What we need to do is if a particular query takes more than a certain time , for example # 10 mins we should be able to stop the query execution for that particular query and move on to the next one

for example

```scala
    do {
        var f = Future(
       spark.sql("some query")) 
       )
    
    f onSucess {
      case suc - > println("Query ran in 10mins")
    }
    
    f failure {
     case fail -> println("query took more than 10mins")
    }
}while(some condition)

var result = Await.ready(f,Duration(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES))
```

I understand that when we call `spark.sql` the control is sent to spark which i need to kill/stop when the duration is over so that i can get back the resources

I have tried multiple things but I am not sure how to solve this.
Any help would be welcomed as i am stuck with this.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile. Could you post the actual code you are using?

Comment: That being said I don't think it's possible to stop a running Spark task without killing the whole job. Thus what you want to achieve would have to be running N jobs rather than 1 job with N tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately I may not be able to put the code here. Let me try another example.also for each call we make to spark.sql() we make I think a different Job Id might be created. So essentially we may have to find a way to kill jobID which is taking more than 10 minutes.